# PHP undeclared static property

Tags: php, singleton

I have class defined like this:

```
class FileSystem
{
    private static $_instance = NULL;

    private function __construct()
    {
        ...
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$_instance === NULL) { // <- line 83
            self::$_instance = new FileSystem;
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    ...
}
```

The error I get when running it is:

> Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property:
>   FileSystem::$_instance in
>   /var/www/html/.../FileSystem.php:83

Server on which the code is running has php 7.1.

Method that calls that class is in another class:

```
public function stream_close()
{
    if (!is_resource($this->_stream)) {
        return false;
    }

    FileSystem::getInstance()->fclose($this->_stream);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you have on line 83?

Comment: I have commented it in code, it is in `getInstance()` method

Comment: construct should not be private

Comment: @SoorajNRaju using a private constructor is exactly what he wants.

Comment: @SoorajNRaju it is in singleton pattern

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ It [works](https://imgur.com/a/bSvTmWf) on my computer

Comment: Works for me too

Comment: As I just run your code, It's working fine.
output: `object(FileSystem)#1 (0) { }`

Comment: @Norgul i run this code on sandbox with php 7.1 and works fine. Meaby we need to see more of your code

Comment: What is the code that throws that error?

Comment: Might be that something else is bugging it...

Comment: Are you using some framework like Symfony that needs a cache clearing?

Answer (score 0):

your code as posted in your question should work fine.
There is one reason of this kind of error and it's when you don't declare you static attribute so your error must be something like you forgot to save or that you have commented that declaration and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however would it be a problem if you deleted it as it doesn't quite solve my problem, and I can't delete my question when it has answers. Obviously problem is not what I think it is.

Comment: if you have a problem with downvote i'll just give you an upvote to avoid sanctions, good luck